# No. of Primes less than or equal to n

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

Let $p(n)$ be a function that gives the no. of primes less than or equal to $n$. I want to deduce that:

## $ p(n) <= \frac{cn}{logn}$ for some constant $c$.

I have shown that for $n$ natural, and $N$ which is the no. of primes s.t. $n<p<=2n$ that for any such prime p:

a) p divides $2nCn$

b) $n^N <2nCn$ & $2nCn <= 4^n$

c) $N<= \frac{log4n}{logn}$

**Attempt:**

Using the above, I can show that

$p(n)=N+p(n/2)$

$p(n)<=\frac{an}{logn} +p(n/2)$

$p(n)<=\frac{an}{logn} + \frac{a(n/2)}{log(n/2)} +p(n/4)$

and I can continue this but I don't know how I can get a closed expression of $\frac{cn}{logn}$ for some constant $c$, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the proof of the prime number theorem on wikipedia for example?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: @GregoryGrant so c is suppose to be 1. No I didn't read it before but I have had a quick glance at it. The proofs there are different to the type of approach intended in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been first proved by Chebyshev, and the proof is not so easy, if you want an estimate with constants close to $1$. He showed
in $1852$ the following explicit inequalities for $\pi(x)$,
holding for all $x\ge x_0$ with some $x_0$ sufficiently large: 
\begin{align*}
c_1 \frac{x}{\log(x)} & < \pi(x) < c_2 \frac{x}{\log(x)}, \\[0.3cm]
c_1 & = \log(2^{1/2}3^{1/3}5^{1/5}30^{-1/30})\approx 0.921292022934, \\[0.3cm]
 c_2 & =\frac{6}{5}c_1\approx 1.10555042752. \\
\end{align*}

Comment: So Chebyshev proved the last part of my intended solution, but I want to prove it as well....is their a proof online?

Comment: Yes, there is a proof online - I suppose you want to look for it for yourself. It can be found also in the number theory book of Tenenbaum.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can find a very elementary proof in Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory on page 82 (theorem 4.6)

Since the proof is elementary the numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not that sharp, but since you want to find a constant c, they do the job.